# How to assign a new value outside the while loop

Tags: c++, visual-studio, while-loop

I have method in c++ called getFuelLevel.

```
   double Sensors::getFuelLevel()
    {
        double fuelLevel= 6000.0;
        double nf = fuelLevel;
        // while loop execution
        while (fuelLevel = 0 ) {
            fuelLevel-1;
            // seting new value for fule level
            fuelLevel = nf;
        }
        return nf;
    }
```

I have tried using a while loop to reduce the value by 1 every time. But it is not working. Instead of outputting the value to console, I need it to return the new value outside the while loop. I want the code to reduce the value of `fuellevel` by 1 every second and return the new value.

Please help, I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: With that debugger you would find that `while (fuelLevel = 0 )` is not correct.

Comment: `fuelLevel-1` does nothing, I think you wanted `fuelLevel=fuelLevel-1` or `fuelLevel--;`

Comment: I am not able to understand what you are trying in the function. The name of the function is clear but it is not clear where you are getting the fuel level from. Is it a hard coded number, such as 6000.0? Is it a member variable? Is it obtained by calling another function? The code in your function does not answer any of those questions for me. I am voting to close because the question is unclear to me.

Comment: Oddly similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43660711/how-to-reduce-a-number-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I want the code to reduce the value of* `fuellevel` *by 1 **every second** and return the new value.*

If you want to decrement the value *every second*, then you could try using the Win32 API function `SetTimer`. See more on:

> [**MSDN Documentation**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

As an aside, your while-loop condition is faulty:

> ```
> while (fuelLevel = 0 ) {
> ```

You should be using the comparison operator `==`, not the assignment operator `=`:

```
while (fuelLevel == 0 ) {
```

You may also want to look over the logic of the code inside your while loop yourself. Simply doing `fuellevel - 1` does not decrement `fuellevel` every second.

Comment: There are standard mechanisms for preforming periodic work. `std::async` and `std::this_thread::sleep_until` can be used to produce a simple timer.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I've never manipulated variables based on a timer, so I didn't know much about it except for the `SetTimer` function. Thanks for the input though, can you provide some links for me? Thanks :)

Comment: [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) and [`std::this_thread::sleep_until`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until). You can find documentation on most standard c++ features at http://en.cppreference.com. `std::async` lets you call a function asynchronously (launches a new thread) and `std::this_thread:sleep_until` can be used in a loop in that async function to cause it to call another function or execute a variable at a regular interval. See [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks for the links ;)